# How to fill a Django form using test Client

Tags: python, django, forms, model, admin

I'd like to test my Django forms, but I got this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

doing this :

```
 self.client.post(self.url, {"title" : 'title', "status" : 2, "user" :1})
```

And my model only need those fields...

Thank you :)

EDIT 1:
Here is the form :

```
class ArticleAdminDisplayable(DisplayableAdmin):

    fieldsets = deepcopy(ArticleAdmin.fieldsets)
    list_display = ('title', 'department', 'publish_date', 'status', )
    exclude = ('related_posts',)
    filter_horizontal = ['categories',]
    inlines = [ArticleImageInline,
               ArticlePersonAutocompleteInlineAdmin,
               ArticleRelatedTitleAdmin,
               DynamicContentArticleInline,
               ArticlePlaylistInline]
    list_filter = [ 'status', 'keywords', 'department', ]

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = Article
```

About the article model there is too much inheritance so you've to trust me the only fields needed (by the model) are title, status and user.

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: only this line : model = Article. And the article model only needs a title, a status and a user..

Comment: Can you show the code for your model and form. Judging by your test data, both ‘status’ and ‘user’ are integerFields

Comment: Here is an example how to parse a form from `response.content` and then use the data with the Django TestClient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603777/633961

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so judging by your `form`, you have a lot of django plugins that you are using. I should have asked for your full `test`, but I think I might understand where some of the problem is coming.

When you `self.client.post`, you are really checking the `view` and not necessarily the form. `{"title" : 'title', "status" : 2, "user" :1}` are 3 values that your `client` is `post`ing.

```
Input Field : Data(Value of the Field)
title       :'title'  # A string
status      : 2       # The number 2
user        : 1       # The number 1
```

Here's some test code that has worked for me. Hopefully it helps you.

forms.py

```
from .models import CustomerEmployeeName


class EmployeeNameForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerEmployeeName
        fields = [
            'employee_choices',
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            ]
```

test_forms.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

from .forms import EmployeeNameForm

class TestEmployeeNameForm(TestCase):
    """
    TESTS: form.is_valid
    """
    # form.is_valid=True
    # middle_name not required.
    # middle_name is blank.
    def test_form_valid_middle_optional_blank(self):
        name_form_data = {'first_name': 'First',     # Required
                            'middle_name': '',       # Optional
                            'last_name': 'Last',     # Required
                            'employee_choices': 'E', # Required
                        }
        name_form = EmployeeNameForm(data=name_form_data)

        self.assertTrue(name_form.is_valid())
```

view.py

```
from .forms import EmployeeNameForm

def create_employee_profile(request):

    if request.POST:
        name_form = EmployeeNameForm(request.POST)

        if name_form.is_valid():
            new_name_form = name_form.save()
            return redirect(new_name_form) #get_absolute_url set on model

        else:
            return render(request,
                'service/template_create_employee_profile.html',
                    {'name_form': name_form}
                    )

    else:
        name_form = EmployeeNameForm(
                        initial={'employee_choices': 'E'}
                        )
        return render(request,
                'service/template_create_employee_profile.html',
                {'name_form': name_form}
                )
```

test_views.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

from service.models import CustomerEmployeeName

class TestCreateEmployeeProfileView(TestCase):
    # TEST: View saves valid object.
    def test_CreateEmployeeProfileView_saves_valid_object(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            '/service/', {
                    'first_name': 'Test',        # Required
                    'middile_name': 'Testy',     # Optional
                    'last_name': 'Testman',      # Required
                    'employee_choices': 'E',     # Required
                    })

        self.assertTrue(CustomerEmployeeName.objects.filter(
            first_name='Test').exists())
```

If you want to post more of your code I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: Actually, all I want to do is testing the "front" form, by using client.post(). And your code make me think that my error may come from the "inlines" field in my form. Do you know how to deal with this field ?

Comment: What Django package are you using? I don’t know what your “inlines” field needs, although it looks like there are 5 values judging by your list.

Comment: I'm on Django 1.9 and I'm using [mezzanine module](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine). The 5 values are other forms of my admin.py

Comment: I haven’t used mezzanine. Are the user and status inputs supposed to be integers?

Comment: Yes about status. About the user, in the form yes, in the model nope !

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Formsets need to have their [`ManagementForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform).

Take a look at [this website](http://schinckel.net/2016/04/30/%28directly%29-testing-django-formsets/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630754/django-formset-unit-test) to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Is that mandatory to have a formset if I want to simulate a POST query ?